# Snake game with C and SDL using linked lists

Tags: c, snake-game, sdl

I am total beginner in C and after reading K&R's chapter 5, I felt I was ready to at least make a simple game using C. I know linked-lists, so since I was making an implementation of Snake, why not?

**main.h**

```
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>

#ifndef MAIN
#define MAIN

#define SCREEN_WIDTH 640
#define SCREEN_HEIGHT 480

SDL_Renderer *getRenderer();

void quit_game(void); 
void set_freeze(bool);

#endif
```

**main.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include "main.h"
#include "snake.h"
#include "apple.h"

void handle_events(SDL_Event* e);
void quit(void);

SDL_Window *window;
SDL_Renderer *renderer;

bool running = false;
bool frozen = false;

bool init(void){
    bool success = true;
    window = NULL;
    renderer = NULL;

    if(SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0){
        printf("SDL could not be initiliazed. SDL_Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
        success = false;
    }

    window = SDL_CreateWindow("snake game", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
    if(!window){
        printf("SDL_Window could not be initialized. SDL_Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
        success = false;
    }
    else{
        renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED);    
    }

    if(!init_snake()){
        printf("snake could not be initialized.\n");
        success = false;
    }

    generate_new_apple_pos();

    running = true;
    return success;
}

int main(int argc, char* args[])
{
    if(!init())
        return -1;
    else{
        SDL_Event e;

        while(running){
            handle_events(&e);

            if(frozen)
                continue;

            SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 255, 255, 224, SDL_ALPHA_OPAQUE);
            SDL_RenderClear(renderer);

            update_snake();
            render_apple();

            SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);

            SDL_Delay(50);
        }
    }

    quit_game();
    return 0;
}

void handle_events(SDL_Event *e)
{
    while(SDL_PollEvent(e) != 0){
        if((*e).type == SDL_QUIT){
            running = false;
        }
        else if((*e).type == SDL_KEYDOWN){
            switch((*e).key.keysym.sym){
                case SDLK_RIGHT:
                    change_snake_direction(RIGHT);
                    break;
                case SDLK_LEFT:
                    change_snake_direction(LEFT);
                    break;
                case SDLK_UP:
                    change_snake_direction(UP);
                    break;
                case SDLK_DOWN:
                    change_snake_direction(DOWN);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}

void quit_game(void){
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    window = NULL;

    SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
    renderer = NULL;

    free_tails();
    SDL_Quit();
}

void set_freeze(bool b)
{
    frozen = b;
}

SDL_Renderer* getRenderer() { return renderer; }
```

**snake.h**

```
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#ifndef SNAKE
#define SNAKE

static const int DEFAULT_X = 500;
static const int DEFAULT_Y = 10;
static const int DEFAULT_WIDTH = 20;
static const int DEFAULT_HEIGHT = 20;

static const int DEFAULT_TAILS_N = 10;

struct TailNode{
    SDL_Rect rect;
    struct TailNode *next;
    struct TailNode *previous;
};

struct Snake{
    int dx;
    int dy;
    int size;
    struct TailNode head;
};

enum direction{LEFT, RIGHT, UP, DOWN};

bool init_snake(void);
void update_snake(void);
void change_snake_direction(int);
void free_tails(void);

#endif
```

**snake.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <math.h>
#include "snake.h"
#include "main.h"
#include "apple.h"

struct Snake snake;
struct TailNode *lasttail;

void push_tail();

bool init_snake()
{
    // default direction
    snake.dx = -1;
    snake.dy = 0;

    // initializes head
    snake.head.rect.x = DEFAULT_X;
    snake.head.rect.y = DEFAULT_Y;
    snake.head.rect.w = DEFAULT_WIDTH;
    snake.head.rect.h = DEFAULT_HEIGHT;
    snake.head.next = NULL;
    snake.head.previous = NULL;

    // sets pointer of last tail to head
    lasttail = &snake.head;

    // pushes default tails
    for(int i = 0; i < DEFAULT_TAILS_N; ++i)
        push_tail();

    return true;
}


void render_tail(SDL_Rect *tail)
{   // renders individual parts of the snake
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(getRenderer(), 204, 175, 175, SDL_ALPHA_OPAQUE);
    SDL_RenderFillRect(getRenderer(), tail);
}

void check_collision()
{
    // fruit collision
    if(abs(snake.head.rect.x - get_apple_posX()) < DEFAULT_WIDTH && abs(snake.head.rect.y - get_apple_posY()) < DEFAULT_HEIGHT){
        push_tail();
        generate_new_apple_pos();
    }

    // border collision
    if(snake.head.rect.x > SCREEN_WIDTH - DEFAULT_WIDTH)
        snake.head.rect.x = 0;
    else if(snake.head.rect.x < 0 - DEFAULT_WIDTH)
        snake.head.rect.x = SCREEN_WIDTH;
    else if(snake.head.rect.y < 0 - DEFAULT_HEIGHT)
        snake.head.rect.y = SCREEN_HEIGHT;
    else if(snake.head.rect.y > SCREEN_HEIGHT - DEFAULT_HEIGHT)
        snake.head.rect.y = 0;
}

void update_snake(void)
{   // iterates over the head and the tail
    for(struct TailNode *ptr = lasttail; ptr != NULL; ptr = (*ptr).previous){
        if((*ptr).previous == NULL){ // in other words, if this "tail" is the head
            snake.head.rect.x += snake.dx * DEFAULT_WIDTH;
            snake.head.rect.y += snake.dy * DEFAULT_HEIGHT;
        }else{ // if it's the snake's body
            if(abs(snake.head.rect.x - (*ptr).rect.x) < DEFAULT_WIDTH && // checks collision with the head
               abs(snake.head.rect.y - (*ptr).rect.y) < DEFAULT_HEIGHT)
                set_freeze(true);

            (*ptr).rect.x = (*ptr).previous->rect.x;
            (*ptr).rect.y = (*ptr).previous->rect.y;
        }

        render_tail(&(*ptr).rect);
    }

    check_collision(); // head-only collision (fruit, border, etc.)
}

void push_tail()
{   // pushes a new tail inside the linked list
    struct TailNode *new_tail = malloc(sizeof(struct TailNode));
    if(new_tail == NULL) 
        quit_game();

    (*new_tail).rect.x = (*lasttail).rect.x + 30;
    (*new_tail).rect.y = (*lasttail).rect.y;
    (*new_tail).rect.w = DEFAULT_WIDTH;
    (*new_tail).rect.h = DEFAULT_HEIGHT;

    (*new_tail).next = NULL;
    (*new_tail).previous = lasttail;

    (*lasttail).next = new_tail;
    lasttail = new_tail;
}

void change_snake_direction(int dir)
{
    if(dir == RIGHT && snake.dx != -1){
        snake.dx = 1;
        snake.dy = 0;
    }
    else if(dir == LEFT && snake.dx != 1){
        snake.dx = -1;
        snake.dy = 0;
    }
    else if(dir == UP && snake.dy != 1){
        snake.dy = -1;
        snake.dx = 0;
    }
    else if(dir == DOWN && snake.dy != -1){
        snake.dy = 1;
        snake.dx = 0;
    }
}

void free_tails()
{
    struct TailNode *tmp;
    struct TailNode *secondtail;
    secondtail = snake.head.next; // we skip the first node (head) because it's allocated in the stack

    while(secondtail != NULL){
        tmp = secondtail;
        secondtail = (*secondtail).next;
        free(tmp);
    }
}
```

**apple.h**

```
#ifndef APPLE
#define APPLE

static const int DEFAULT_APPLE_WIDTH = 20;
static const int DEFAULT_APPLE_HEIGHT = 20;

void render_apple(void);
void generate_new_apple_pos(void);

int get_apple_posX(void);
int get_apple_posY(void);

#endif
```

**apple.c**

```
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include "main.h"
#include "apple.h"

SDL_Rect apple;

void generate_new_apple_pos(void);

void render_apple()
{
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(getRenderer(), 226, 106, 106, SDL_ALPHA_OPAQUE);
    SDL_RenderFillRect(getRenderer(), &apple);
}

void generate_new_apple_pos(void)
{
    apple.x = (rand() % (SCREEN_WIDTH - 0 + 1));
    apple.y = (rand() % (SCREEN_HEIGHT - DEFAULT_APPLE_HEIGHT + 1));
    apple.w = DEFAULT_APPLE_WIDTH;
    apple.h = DEFAULT_APPLE_HEIGHT;
}

int get_apple_posX(void)
{
    return apple.x;
}
int get_apple_posY(void)
{
    return apple.y;
}
```

**ANY** suggestions and tips to better this code are welcome, I'm trying to improve my fundamentals so I can develop bigger projects in C.

A few questions though:

1. Am I using headers correctly? Or is it a mess? What can I do to
   improve the organization?
2. Is my implementation of a linked list alright?
3. The `snake`'s `dx` and `dy` values are either 1, 0, or -1. Should I make it a `short` instead? Or even `char`?
4. How can I make `struct TailNode` private to `snake.c`?
5. When do I use `static const` over macro `#define`s? Do I use `static const` when I want my variable private?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Running but failed?

```
running = true;
return success;
```

In all cases you set `running` to true even if `success` is false. This seems like an odd decision. Also, you `init_snake` regardless of the success or failure of previous calls, which does not seem correct. You should be early-bailing in such circumstances.

### Main's early-return

After this:

```
if(!init())
    return -1;
```

your `else` is redundant and can be removed.

### Structural dereferencing

`(*e).type`

should be

`e->type`

Similarly for `(*ptr).previous`, `(*new_tail)`, etc.

### `const` arguments

You do not modify `e` in `void handle_events(SDL_Event *e)`. As long as it does not cause callback pointer type incompatibility issues, consider making that argument `const SDL_Event *e`.

That aside: why are you passing in `e` at all? The way it is written now, `e` should just be a local variable.

### Non-exported functions

For functions like `init` that are not intended for export to other translation units, mark them `static`. The same is true for any global variables that will not be referenced in other translation units.